# Открытике activity через startActivity в Widget

Tags: android, android-widgets

Товарищи, следущая задача:
Необходимо при добавление *widget* проверять некое условие и если оно выполняется - запускать активити. Проблема в том, что если в первом *onUpdate* вызвать *context.startActivity(...)*, то виджет не отрисовывается на экране.
Единственны способ которы я нашел, для обхода этой ситуации, выглядит так:

```
...   
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                getOpenActivityIntent(widgetId))   
...
```

*Handler* тоже не дает эффекта (не открывает даже *activity*).
Возможно кто-то знает как обойти это поведение?

Answer (score 0):

вы должны создавать активити от имени того активити/контекста, в котором вы находитесь сейчас. [packageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) знает [intent для запуска activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String))

в текущем контексте [запросите packagemanager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager()), возьмите у него интент для запуска активити (выше) и выполните [startActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) с этим интентом